# In a priority queue, which takes precedence, a Comparator or a Comparable's natural ordering?

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator, comparable

If I have a PriorityQueue that has a Comparator, and an element class that implements the Comparable class, and their ordering conflicts, how will the queue handle the ordering? Does it throw an exception or ignore one of the ordering rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read there: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

*The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used.*

So, actually, if it has a special `Compatator` given as the construction time, the natural order comparaison (the one given by the `Comparable` interface) will be **ignored**.

This is the constructor you need to use in order to have the behavior I just described:

```
PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)
```

*Creates a PriorityQueue with the specified initial capacity that orders its elements according to the specified comparator.*

Comment: I can only post a question every 20mins, and can only accept an answer after 1-10? minutes, this is the perfect way to build a scalable server.